# Cursor variable reuse

Tags: android

I'm using a cursor in a while loop to execute multiple queries on my database, so each time Content Resolver returns new cursor object instance. I am uncertain about proper way I should reuse the cursor during each iteration of the loop:

1. Close it once, after all operations being performed

   ```
   Cursor c;
   try {
       while(condition) {
           c = Context.getContentResolver().query(...);
           // fetching values
       }
   } finally {
       if (c != null) {
           c.close()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Close it at the end of each iteration

   ```
   Cursor c;
   try {
       while(condition) {
           c = Context.getContentResolver().query(...);
           // fetching values
           if (c != null) {
               c.close()
           }
       }
   } finally {
       if (c != null) {
           c.close()
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create new cursor variable inside while loop

   ```
   while(condition) {
       Cursor c = Context.getContentResolver().query(...);
       try {
           // fetching values
       } finally {
           if (c != null) {
               c.close()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Case 1 is bad since you're assigning a new cursor in your loop and you only get to close the last assigned cursor.
- Case 2 and 3 are very similar but I prefer case 3 because with case 2 you can break out of your loop unexpectedly but with case 3 you keep the cursor in the loop scope and the loop can keep running.

Comment: And looks cleanest as well imo.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples the third variant is most useful because you open-close the same Cursor object in each loop. You lost nothing: niether memory leaks no app+db crashes.

Comment: I thought for a while there's performance difference when declaring variable inside loop, but no more.

Comment: @tomwyr, of course, in each iteration your code generates new variable. But you really need it. Otherwise, it would not work:)